# Firebase Phone Authentication not showing app name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have added firebase phone authentication to my android app.
It worked well, but the the app name is not included in the sms verification message as it appears in the sms template in the firebase console:
(%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.).

The message I receive looks like: 
(%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code)

I have this problem for both debug and release versions of my app.

So, how to add the app name to this message.

Comment: You cannot edit that message but only change its language. Google might be working on it.

Comment: i have the same issue. did it get solved for you?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It was by Firebase. Maybe they were testing this new feature.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 10):

I believe they get the app name corresponding to your Android package name from the Google Play Store. So until your app is on the Play Store, they won't be able to show the app name in the SMS message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, bojeil.. It makes me a sense!