# How to configure %APP_NAME% in firebase app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I configured the phone authentication service
However when i receive the SMS it displays something atrocious.

I get something like `"firebase-production.app..."`

How to fix it ?

Comment: Seems like a good question for [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).  None of the related questions completely resolve the issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48848564/4815718 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/46756272/4815718 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/44888725/4815718.  Apparently, changing the "Public-facing name" in the Project Settings of the Firebase Console has no effect.

Comment: For me, updating the "Public facing name" has been working.

Answer (score 18):

According to [Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714), to change the `APP_NAME` you can change the **Public-facing name** field on the Settings page.

[image]

You may have to enable Google as a sign-in provider to enable the **Public-facing name** setting, which is no longer enabled by default, per this question: [Where did the public settings of a firebase project go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77188427/6286797)

Comment: But that don't work. At least on ios and android apps.

Comment: there may be other settings. i set the public facing name but it does not show in the SMS

Comment: I came here because the password reset emails had awful app names - this answer fixed that for me - ie it did change %APP_NAME%.

Comment: Which is in the firebase (Project settings->Public settings)

Comment: change Public-facing name didn't fix problem with awful xxx.firebaseapp.com

Comment: Anyone find the answer for above ?

Answer (score 11):

For Android and iOS, the App store and Play store name are used as those are already vetted before release. If this is a web app, the page's domain name is used as the app name. The reason is because this is the only verifiable identifier associated with the web app. The same thing is used for OAuth redirects. When you sign in with Google to your app, the user would see a message: `Continue to www.example.com`.

If you are using Firebase hosting, you can switch to using custom domains. Using the project name is insecure as anyone can set any name on an app. I could create a Firebase project and call it Google. Nothing can stop me from doing so.

Answer (score 8):

It's in the `Project settings`'s `General` tab.

[image]

Comment: It's not working, changed the Public-facing name didn't fix the problem still xxx.firebaseapp.com in SMS otp

Comment: The public-facing name option is now only available if you change the "Environment type" to "Production".

Answer (score 1):

Though you cannot change the template, you can change the name of the app from something like `xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com` to your App name.

For this, you need to go to your **Project Settings** on Firebase console and under **App Check** tab make sure to register your apps. Just click on your app to enable **SafetyNet** for **Android**.

If you've already filled in all the information for **iOS**, your app should already be registered.

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS and Android** - The SMS messages draw the app's name from the App Store / Play Store, Once the app is published. There may be a slight delay (a week or two).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase Web SDK, there is a way to change this url.

Actually, firebase puts this url from **authDomain** from firebase config.

To change this configuration, you need to set your own domain in firebase console under Authorised Domains section. Please follow this to do that:

1. Go to **Authentication** > **Settings** > **Authorised domains**.
2. Click on **Add domain** and add your domain there.
3. Last step is to put this domain in authDomain in firebase config in client application.

   ```
   const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "<Put your domain here>",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "..."
   };
   ```