# Firebase SMS verification content

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

it says

```
Message
%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.
```

however even i setup the Project name, the sms content still showing `projectid.firebaseapp.com`

how to modify sms content?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possibly to change the content of the SMS,  you can change the name of the app.According to [Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714), to change the APP_NAME you can change the Public-facing name field on the Settings page.

For this, you need to go to your Project settings->Public settings on Firebase console and update the "Public facing name”

You can refer to this StackOverflow [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888516) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135993).

Answer (score 0):

After 2023 update:

If you want to just change the APP_NAME, you'll need to enable Google Sign-in in your Firebase project, which will prompt for a public-facing name. This will be your APP_NAME for the templates.

The public-facing name is not there by default, so enabling Google Sign-in will make that field. You can later change this in the project settings in Firebase. Thanks Firebase support.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531060/how-do-i-display-my-firebase-post-firebase-oct-2023-update-app-name-instead-of#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20just,in%20will%20make%20that%20field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531060/how-do-i-display-my-firebase-post-firebase-oct-2023-update-app-name-instead-of#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20just,in%20will%20make%20that%20field).