# How do I display my Firebase (Post Firebase Oct 2023 Update) app name instead of app ID at the bottom of my authentication email?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

**Context**
I have a web app in Firebase, with a connected domain and hosted site through Firebase.

For the user email authentication template it has %APP_NAME% (i.e. 'Thanks, your %APP_NAME% team.') as a variable throughout the email template, but it actually just shows the app's ID as the APP_NAME in the emails sent, which is pretty gross to look at and not professional.

**The Problem**
The problem is I need this APP_NAME to reflect my actual project name, not the id.

**What I Tried**

- I changed my app name in settings expecting it to change the variable, and nothing happened.
- I tried changing the project ID directly, which you can't change for the project.
- I tried changing the email template itself, which is not allowed to 'help prevent spam'.
- I connected a custom domain to see if it would default to that, and that didn't do anything either.

So I don't see anything else left to try.

Is this a bug from the new Firebase update, or am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

**SOLVED**
I reached out to Firebase directly and they answered it.

If you want to just change the APP_NAME, you'll need to enable Google Sign-in in your Firebase project, which will prompt for a public-facing name. This will be your APP_NAME for the templates.

The public-facing name is not there by default, so enabling Google Sign-in will make that field. You can later change this in the project settings in Firebase. Thanks Firebase support.