# Where did the public settings of a firebase project go?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I maintain a couple of firebase projects within the Google Cloud Platform. Yesterday I created a new one, which is identical to my other projects. Within my setup process I documented that I need to change the public facing app name. This is so that the %APP_NAME% parameter in mails is usable accordingly.

Within the firebase console (cog wheel > project setting > General) there should be a block with public facing settings. These settings are currently gone.

Where has it gone?

[firebase cli webinterface where settings are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQnIE.png)

the first project was created automatically.

creating another project manually.

searched on google.
looked into the the docs.
looked into the firebase changelogs.

all to no avail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered this too, and my workaround was to add "Google" as a sign-in provider (which will reveal these settings, ie. `Public-facing name` and `Support email` ) then disabled and remove "Google" as a sign-in provider.

After that I can actually have these settings available for my "Email/Password" provider, and can be referenced in my email templates by variables such as %APP_NAME%.

This is not a bug but an expected behavior. In the past, at the time that the project was created, the OAuth Client was created automatically. However, some developers did not use Google as an authentication method, and the OAuth Client was added to the project automatically, regardless of whether it was used. In the case of new projects, this does not occur, and the OAuth Client will only be generated upon activation of the Google method in the console. In this way you will be able to see the Public Facing Name.

Comment: I just got a reply from Firebase about this.  They say it's intended behaviour.  It must only be for new projects as I have older projects with the setting without Google auth.

Comment: @Jayen yes same here. I have now mentioned that even if just using the Email/Password provider these settings are necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Ran into the same problem and used this work-around.

Comment: @gkoromia glad this helped  Didn't sound like Firebase were going to fix this so hopefully this helps some others too

Answer (score 0):

The public facing name is the name presented to users when they are shown any public instances of your project. For example, this will be the name displayed on emails that your users receive after creating an account with your app.

When you create a new project, the public setting is not included unless you enable Firebase Authentication with Google Sign-in provider.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Authentication -> Sign-in method
2. Add new Provider
3. Choose **Google**, toggle the enable button

Then, you will see text fields for the Public-facing Name and Supporting Email. The basic idea is to enable Google as one of the providers, not just Email/Password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but an expected behavior. In the past, at the time that the project was created, the OAuth Client was created automatically. However, some developers did not use Google as an authentication method, and the OAuth Client was added to the project automatically, regardless of whether it was used.
In the case of new projects, this does not occur, and the OAuth Client will only be generated upon activation of the Google method in the console. In this way you will be able to see the Public Facing Name.