# Where can I find the public settings of a Firebase project?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Where have the public settings of a Firebase project disappeared to? In the Firebase console (cog wheel > project settings > General), there used to be a section for public-facing settings, but now it seems to be missing. How can I access these settings again?

I'm trying to modify the 'Public-facing name' and 'Support email,' but I can't find them in Project settings under General. Despite extensive research and reaching out to support, I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm hopeful that someone can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77188427/11382012
As per this thread, you have to add google as sign in provider first. Check it out.